# Is the order of results coming from a list comprehension guaranteed?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

When using a list comprehension, is the order of the new list guaranteed in any way? As a contrived example, is the following behavior guaranteed by the definition of a list comprehension:

```
>> a = [x for x in [1,2,3]]
>> a
[1, 2, 3]
```

Equally, is the following equality guaranteed:

```
>> lroot = [1, 2, 3]
>> la = [x for x in lroot]
>> lb = []
>> for x in lroot:
     lb.append(x)
>> lb == la
True
```

Specifically, it's the ordering I'm interested in here.

Comment: Yes, it's guaranteed. It's a sequence.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Yes, the list comprehension preserves the order of the original iterable (if there is one).
If the original iterable is ordered (list, tuple, file, etc.), that's the order you'll get in the result.  If your iterable is unordered (set, dict, etc.), there are no guarantees about the order of the items.

Comment: With sets and dicts, I believe there is a guarantee that the order won't change if the data doesn't change. e.g. given a set `s`, the following will always be true: `[x for x in s] == [x for x in s]`.

Comment: Does that also mean that the execution of the comprehension is in that order? I.e. will [x for x in s if p(x)] call p(x) in the order of s or could (even if only theoretically) that be in a different order and the result somehow "sorted" back to the correct order afterwards?

Comment: @JohnFouhy Yes, but it's a bit more nuanced than that for dicts. Output order between sequential list comprehension calls can change based on the operation even if the original data does not change (example from B. Slatkin's Effective Python):
`chile_ranks = {'ghost': 1, 'habanero': 2, 'cayenne': 3}`
`rank_dict = {rank: name for name, rank in chile_ranks.items()}`
`print({name for name in rank_dict.values()})`
`print({len(name) for name in rank_dict.values()})`

Answer (score 3):

Yes, a list is a sequence. Sequence order is significant.

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while, but since I came up with a similar question myself recently, and needed a bit more explanation to understand what this comes down to exactly, I'll add my two cents, may it help someone else in the future! :)
*More specifically this is about the order of values resulting from a list comprehension operation.*

---

Imagine you have the following list:

```py
list_of_c = [a, b, c, d, e]
```

---

I want to *round* the variables in that list using the following list comprehension:

```py
list_of_d = [round(value, 4) for value in list_of_c]
```

---

*My question was whether this would mean that the order resulting from the list comprehension would be the following:*

```py
list_of_d = [round_a, round_b, round_c, round_d, round_e]
```

---

And the answer I received very kindly from @juanpa.arrivillaga , was that indeeded, **YES** that was the case!